# Mathematical symbol for "has"

Tags: notation

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there was a symbol for "has" so intead of saying $x \in A$, we could say something like "$A$ has $x$", they both mean the same thing but I was just wondering if there was another way to say it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say $x$ is an element of $A$, or are you looking for some symbol other than $\in$ to denote 'has'?

Comment: `A \ni x` $A \ni x$

Comment: Adding to what @Rahul said, you can also write **\owns** to generate $\owns$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I have seen $\ni$ used for this purpose.  That is, $x\in A \iff A\ni x$

Comment: In Unicode it is called "Contains As Member" and is encoded at U+220B.

Answer (score 6):

The better term to use would be "$A$ includes $x$" instead of "$A$ has $x$", and as Rahul quickly answered, that can be expressed by $A \ni x \iff x\in A$.

***Set inclusion*** is the conventional concept for describing "element - set" relations, which can be discussed with respect to a set which includes an element ($A\ni x$) or an element being "included in" or "belonging to" a set ($x \in A$).

This is analogous to the conventional reference to the relations of **set containment**, encompassing the relations of $A$ containing another set $B$: $A\supset B$ and of a set B being contained in a set $A$: $B\subset A$.